# What do you call the act of a political staff of taking ideas from a think tank?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call the act of a political staff of taking ideas from a think tank? I thought about the idea "get inspiration from", but it wouldn't work, because taking the recommendations and turning them into policy is almost like copy and paste. Also, "get inspiration from" sounds like something an artist would do and not a political campaign staff in order to build a political platform to run on.

Think of a political campaign staff taking a policy recommendation from a think tank and adding it to the political platform a candidate is running on.

Comment: The words **borrowing** and **adopting** are frequently used in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "Think Tank," If you could include a bit more context on that I bet I could help you out. :)

Comment: As written, this seems like a very subjective question, without clear criteria for a single answer. *I* would say ***follow the guidance of***. But it's not obvious exactly what you are trying to describe.

Comment: You will often hear it exactly as you said it "take ideas from a think tank" in any tense.  Also get.  Often also (from think tank to policy) some variety of "formalised" or "developed".  If there is nuance you can use any variety of "taking/getting": borrowed/found/stole/disinterred/resurrected/bought/smuggled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to convey that the ideas were "accepted" in a neutral, rational, objective mood, you could say they *adopted* these ideas.

> adopt (verb): to accept formally and put into effect; *adopt a constitutional amendment*

However, if you wanted to convey some enthusiasm in the process, you would rather say they *embraced* these ideas.

> embrace (verb): to take up especially readily or gladly; *embrace a cause*

And if your intention were instead to highlight that these political actors have chosen to blend these new ideas into their existing other ones, you could say that they *incorporated* them.

> incorporate (verb): to unite or work into something already existent so as to form an indistinguishable whole

([1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt), [2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace), [3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorporate) from Merriam Webster)